# How to use spirit X3 parse into a class with constructor containing parameters？

Tags: c++14, boost-spirit

I am a new man on using spirit x3, I read some document from official site or from other github repositories. But, I can not find how to parse into a class with parameters. I referred to the former question: [Boost-Spirit (X3) parsing without default constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854389/boost-spirit-x3-parsing-without-default-constructors)

I wrote a sample to test it, I will present my codes in the following area. My pain is how to use x3::_attr, and how to pass parsed parameters to the class constructor?

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include  <iostream>
#include <vector>

 struct MyPair {
  MyPair(int x, int y) : mx(x), my(y) {};
  int mx;
  int my;
  };

 class MyDu {
   public:
    MyDu() {};
    MyDu(int x, int y) : mx(x), my(y) {};
     int mx;
     int my;
  };

  int main()
{
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
using x3::int_;

std::vector<MyPair> pairs;
MyDu myDu;
char const *first = "11:22", *last = first + std::strlen(first);

//auto pair = x3::rule<struct pair_, std::vector<MyPair> >{}
//  = (int_ >> ':' >> int_)
//  [([&](auto& ctx) {
//  auto& attr = x3::_attr(ctx);
//  using boost::fusion::at_c;
//  return x3::_val(ctx).emplace_back(at_c<0>(attr), at_c<1>(attr));
//      })]
//;
auto pair = x3::rule<class MyDu_, MyDu >{}
    = (int_ >> ':' >> int_)
    [([&](auto& ctx) {
    auto& attr = x3::_attr(ctx);
    using boost::fusion::at_c;
    //return x3::_val(ctx)(at_c<0>(attr), at_c<1>(attr));
    ctx = MyDu(at_c<0>(attr), at_c<1>(attr));
    return x3::_val(ctx);
        })]
;

//bool parsed_some = parse(first, last, pair % ',', pairs);
bool parsed_some = parse(first, last, pair, myDu);

if (parsed_some) {
    std::cout << "Parsed the following pairs" << std::endl;
    //for (auto& p : pairs) {
    //  std::cout << p.mx << ":" << p.my << std::endl;
    //}
    std::cout<<myDu.mx<<","<<myDu.my<<std::endl;
}

system("pause");
```

}

Any one who can fix my error, and parse into a class in my code ? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you were missing the way to assign to the rule's value using `_val`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/171ab34ab5e612db)</kbd>**

```cpp
    #include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    
    struct MyDu {
        MyDu(int x, int y) : mx(x), my(y){};
        int mx;
        int my;
    };
    
    int main() {
        namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
        using x3::int_;
    
        MyDu myDu{1,2};
        std::string const s = "11:22";
    
        auto assign = [](auto& ctx) {
            using boost::fusion::at_c;
            auto& attr = x3::_attr(ctx);
    
            x3::_val(ctx) = MyDu(at_c<0>(attr), at_c<1>(attr));
        };
    
        auto pair = x3::rule<class MyDu_, MyDu>{} = (int_ >> ':' >> int_)[assign];
    
        if (parse(begin(s), end(s), pair, myDu)) {
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << myDu.mx << ", " << myDu.my << "\n";
        }
    }
```

Prints

```
Parsed: 11, 22
```